# Как добавить к текущей категории класс?

Tags: php, wordpress

у меня есть список категорий и как добавить к текущей категории класс 'active', буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
   $categories = get_terms(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'NameTaxonomy',
                    )
                );
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $cat_name = $category->name;
                $cat_id = $category->term_id;
                $cat_slug = $category->slug;
                $cat_link = get_category_link($cat_id);
                echo '<a href="' . $cat_link . '" class="class">' . $cat_name . '</a>';
 
    }
```

Comment: ``echo '<a href="' . $cat_link . '" class="class active">' . $cat_name . '</a>';``

Comment: @YaMus Здравствуйте, у меня список категорий выводиться. И нужно на категории на которой я нахожусь добавить класс active. А не ко всем.

Comment: На будущее, так и надо писать :) Покажите как происходит переход между "категориями". Скорее всего через $_GET; (example.com/?category=1) Если так, то вы должны сравнивать id категорию с категорией внутри ``foreach`` ``$active = ''; if($_GET['category'] == $cat_id) $active = ' active';`` и теперь добавляем ``echo '<a href="' . $cat_link . '" class="class'.$active.'">' . $cat_name . '</a>';``